# Another word for the pokemon "Ditto"

Tags: single-word-requests

Having the ability to transform into things that it came into contact with

Is there a single term for the above phrase?

Comment: Probably not.  I suggest that you look at words related to "synthetic", "replicant", "doppelgänger" and ''morph''.

Answer (score 1):

I can’t think of any word with that precise meaning, but perhaps **shapeshifter** is close? It doesn’t incorporate the “coming into contact” part of the definition you gave, but I’m not sure such a specific word exists in English.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not, at least not as far as I'm aware.

The closest I can get is

> touched-object-cloning

and other, similar abominations.

The difficulty is that it would have to be an adjective, but contain the ability to explain the relation between two objects in addition to a verb, which simply can't fit into a single adjective without taking shortcuts.

"Ditto" means

> having qualities in common

according to [Marriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/ditto), which misses out on all sorts of information you would require to make the word concise.

I suggest you look at the link and see whether you can draw any inspiration from that. Hope I could help.

Edit: Perhaps something like **imitate**

> 1 : to follow as a pattern, model, or example
>
> 2 : mimic, counterfeit can imitate his father's booming voice
>
> 3 : to be or appear like : resemble
>
> 4 : to produce a copy of : reproduce

or **mimic**?

Comment: This wasn’t clear in the question, but Ditto only needs to see the Pokémon in order to be able to transform into it.